# Drilling conical holes into Metal (Lathe)

Tags: drill, hole, lathe

I need to make a hole that is 11.5mm wide at the bottom, 12.2mm wide at the top and 34mm deep into a metal cylinder. The dimensions may vary. I have a lathe.

I was thinking of getting a 11.5mm drill bit and drilling 34mm deep, then getting a 13.2mm bit and drilling 1-2mm deep and then use a fine round file on the lathe and try to make the transition as smooth as possible per hand.

Comment: Use the tool holder set at an angle. Holding a file by hand is dangerous.

Comment: What home improvement project does this relate to?

Comment: This is a "taper boring" operation on a lathe.  Drill out most of the material with different sized drills, then clean up the taper with a tool on the compound slide.

Comment: Did you ever ask when you'd need trigonometry in real life as a student? Well, here you are! Because that's where the correct setting of the compound slide comes from...

Comment: do any of the available step drill bits line up closely with your measurements?